# Propositional Logic simplification

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I was wondering if anyone could help me to understand how this is simplified:

P v (P ^ Q)

The answer is:
1) (P ^ T) v (P v Q) - apply Identity.
2) P ^ (T v Q) - apply Distributive.
3) (P ^ T) - apply Identity.
4) P - apply identity.

Steps 3, and 4 I get.

I don't see how step 1 is an application of Identity. 
Identity states: `P v T = T`... `P v F = P`... `P ^ T = P`... `P ^ F = F`...

So from: `P v (P ^ Q)`

How is step 1 applying identity? I can't seem to understand how that uses identity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step one is taking $P$ and expressing it as $P\land T$ which as one of your identities states, is equivalent to $P$.

So $$\color{blue}{\bf P} \lor (P\land Q) \equiv \color{blue}{\bf (P \land T)} \lor (P\land Q)$$

Comment: Hmm, So I guess it's applying the Identity Law backwards... In terms of `P ^ T = P`, they have applied it the other way around...

In that case, I'm not totally sure when I should KNOW when I should apply the left side of the law or the right side...

Would you please be able to elaborate on that? I was assuming I would always want to convert the form from the left hand side to the right, not the other way.

Comment: Yes, equality (equivalence) is "commutative": $a = b$ is just another way of saying $b = a$. If you have $a = b$, and know either $a$ or $b$, you can exchange (substitute) one for the other.

Comment: Okay, I think I get it. My only concern is if I might make the expression more bloated - because I apply the wrong side of a law.

I don't know if the brute force "Find a law that will work with this expression. Keep going until no more laws can be applied" approach would work. Is that a valid way to go about simplifying?

Comment: It works, but the more you work with expressions, the more "intuition" you develop, just as with anything. ;-)

Comment: Okay then, thanks!